# Indefinite Integration of $(\arctan(x))^2$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$
\mbox{Hello. I was wondering how to integrate this:}\quad
\int\arctan^{2}\left(x\right)\,{\rm d}x 
$$

Do I first do a u-substitution first ?.

Comment: According to Wolfram Alpha (http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=arctan%5E2%28x%29&random=false), you don't have an elementary indefinite integral. The answer involves the dilogarithm function. Sure this is the actual question and not some definite integral where you may be able to apply a clever "trick"?

Comment: Same comment as Deepak using another CAS. Where is this integral coming from ?

Comment: "Do I first do a u-substitution?" - This is a meaningless question until you specify which substitution you are going to use.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, the indefinite integral [cannot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) be [expressed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28differential_algebra%29) in terms of elementary functions. However, on $[0,1]$ the result is $\dfrac\pi4\bigg(\dfrac\pi4+\ln2\bigg)-\text{Catalan}$.

Comment: See also [polylogarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) and [Catalan's constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_constant).

Answer (score 0):

This integral is done by using integration by parts. We have:
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int (\arctan(x))^2 dx = \int x^{'} (\arctan(x))^2 dx =\\
&& x \arctan(x)^2 - \int x \cdot 2 \arctan(x) \cdot \frac{1}{1+x^2} dx =\\
&& x \arctan(x)^2 - \log(1+x^2) \arctan(x) + \int \frac{\log(1+x^2)}{1+x^2} dx =\\
&&  x \arctan(x)^2 - \log(1+x^2) \arctan(x) + \frac{1}{2 \imath}\int \left(\log(x+\imath)+\log(x-\imath)\right) \left(\frac{1}{x-\imath}-\frac{1}{x+\imath}\right) dx =\\
&& x \arctan(x)^2 - \log(1+x^2) \arctan(x) + \frac{1}{2 \imath}\left( \frac{1}{2} \log(x-\imath)^2 - \frac{1}{2} \log(x+\imath)^2\right) + \\
&&\frac{1}{2 \imath}\int \left( \frac{\log(x+\imath)}{x-\imath} - \frac{\log(x-\imath)}{x+\imath}\right)dx =\\
&&x \arctan(x)^2 - \log(1+x^2) \arctan(x) + Im\left( \frac{1}{2} \log(x-\imath)^2 +\log(2 \imath) \log(x-\imath) - Li_2(\frac{x-\imath}{-2 \imath})\right) 
\end{eqnarray}